# Weighting loss function by confusion matrix

Tags: tensorflow, keras, confusion-matrix, loss-function

As far as I understand it's possible to weight true positives and true negatives in the keras class weight parameter.

But is there also a way to weight false positives and false negatives?

Or are these interdepended numbers in a confusion matrix?

To give a bit more context: I'm trying to add weights to a binary cross entroy loss function, but I'd like to weight true postiives, true negatives, false positives and false negatives.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: downvoter, any productive comments?

Comment: I've already provided you with the solution to this. `tp`, `tn`, `fp` and `fn` are from confusion matrix.

Comment: Yes, but it seems that this is causing a bias. The network converged to predict false for everything no matter how I adjust the weights.

Comment: So maybe the weight values were adjusted wrongly. My previous answer was exactly what you asked here,

Comment: I tried quite a few things with changing sign for the weights etc. Is it possible that I needs t be included in the log function somehow and multiplying the whole term with it is not allowed?

Comment: I think that you misunderstood the connection between loss and pay off. Changing the weights to expected pay off does something different than you expect.

Comment: Ok very possible I misunderstand. I’m trying to connect your answer to this one: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/327376/binary-cross-entropy-vs-mse-loss-function-when-asymmetric-payoffs. Is this a different approach?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165002/discussion-between-marcin-mozejko-and-nickpick).